# When running a python script from a docker container does it use a "local" version of python? (docker container has only 300mb of GPU memory)

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

When I run nvidia's tensorflow docker container and type `nvidia-smi` I can see my memory usage at `39241MiB / 40960MiB`. This happens if I run `nvidia-smi` outside the container too.

As a result when I run a python script from inside the container, the GPU has only ~380MB memory available.

Now this might sound stupid, but when I run a python script from inside a container does it somehow run it by using the "remaining" system resources, instead of the resources allocated by the container?

`nvidia-smi` from inside the docker container:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100-SXM...  On   | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P0    48W / 400W |  39241MiB / 40960MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And from outside:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100-SXM...  On   | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P0    48W / 400W |  39241MiB / 40960MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |             Disabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2322      C   /usr/bin/python3                39239MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Clearly `/usr/bin/python3` is using all memory, but I have no idea what to do about it.